# getting multiple arrays from single mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

This may be simpler than I am making it, but I'm fairly new to php/mySQL and have hit a bit of a roadblock.

I have data from two tables

1-Employers *has general contact info*

2-Duties *has work that the employer is responsible for*

It is a one to many relationship as each employer has many duties. I know how to display a list of duties when I am displaying each employer independently, But in this application I need to display a list of employers with the duties each employer has after their company info with all companies listed on the same page.

The way I currently have it I get a

for every duty with the employer duplicated each time.

The controller

```
// Display employment

    try
    {
      $result = $pdo->query('SELECT d.*, m.*,
      date_format(start_date,"%M, %Y") AS started,
      date_format(end_date,"%M, %Y") AS ended FROM employers m
      LEFT JOIN duties d ON d.e_id = m.id');
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
      $error = 'Error fetching employers from the database!' . $e->getMessage();
      include '/error.html.php';
      exit();
    }

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
      $employers[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'name' => $row['name'],
      'city' => $row['city'],
      'state' => $row['state'],
      'started' => $row['started'],
      'ended' => $row['ended'],
      'title' => $row['title'],
      'duty' => $row['duty']
      );
    }
```

The View

```
<section id="employers">
    <h2>Employers</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($employers as $employer): ?>
        <li>
            <?php htmlout($employer['id']); ?>
            <?php htmlout($employer['name']); ?>
            <?php htmlout($employer['city']); ?>
            <?php htmlout($employer['state']); ?>
            <?php htmlout($employer['duty']); ?>
       </li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group all your duties for each employee, you should modify your loop.
Here an example

```
// Initialize employers
$employers = array();

// The current employee ID
$employeeId = false;

// The current new employee
$newEmployee = false;

// Loop on each line of employee-duty
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    // Check if we have to add a new employee
    if ($employeeId == false || $row['id'] != $employeeId)
    {
        // Store previous employee if exists
        if ($newEmployee != false)
            $employers[] = $newEmployee;

        // Create new employee
        $newEmployee = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'city' => $row['city'],
            'state' => $row['state'],
            'started' => $row['started'],
            'ended' => $row['ended'],
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'duty' => array()
        );

        // Set the new employee ID
        $employeeId = $row['id'];
    }

    // In all case, add the duty
    $newEmployee['duty'][] = $row['duty'];
}

// Save the last employee that will not be saved in the loop
if ($newEmployee != false)
    $employers[] = $newEmployee;
```

At the end of this code, you will have all employee (unique) with all duties in the `duty` entry.

**Important**: Another solution will be to modify your SQL query, and use a *group by* and *aggregate functions* to do the stuff on the SQL server side. This will simplify the code in the PHP side.

good luck.